# want to cut the display text of sidebar facet in dspace 4.x XMLUI

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dspace

[image: sidebarfacet of dspace 4.x XMLUI]

In the above, items under **"DDC Subject"** is showing with **'::'** like -> **"DEWEY DECIMAL CLASSIFICATION::GENERALITIES::Bibliography (1)"**, I want to display it like -> **"Bibliography (1)"**.
For this purpose I have written the following script in the file **[dspace-install]/webapps/xmlui/static/js/discovery/search-control.js**->

```html
function cutText(){
 
   var headvalue =  $('div#aspect_discovery_Navigation_list_discovery ul li h2').innerHTML;

   if(headvalue.match('DDC Subject')){
  var displaytext = $('#aspect_discovery_Navigation_list_discovery ul li ul li a').innerHTML;
  var y = displaytext.split("::");
  if(y.len>1)
   var display = y[y.len-1];

  alert(display);
  $('#aspect_discovery_Navigation_list_discovery ul li ul li a').innerHTML = display;

 }
     }
```

But its not working. Can anyone help?

Taking **@euler's** suggestion
Now I have done the following-> 
I have modified **dspace.cfg** file with the following ->

```html
choices.plugin.dc.subject.ddc = ddcE
choices.presentation.dc.subject.ddc = lookup
vocabulary.plugin.ddcE.hierarchy.store = false
vocabulary.plugin.ddcE.hierarchy.suggest = false
vocabulary.plugin.ddcE.delimiter = "::"
```

and the "**ddcE**"  is defined in my **input-forms.xml** file like ->

```html
    <field>
         <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
         <dc-element>subject</dc-element>
         <dc-qualifier>ddc</dc-qualifier>
         <!-- An input-type of twobox MUST be marked as repeatable -->
         <repeatable>true</repeatable>
         <label>Subject (From DDC)</label>
         <input-type>twobox</input-type>
         <hint>Enter appropriate subject Division/Sub-division from DDC 23rd Edition(upto 3rd Summary)</hint>
         <required>You must enter at least one Division/Sub-division from DDC 23rd Edition(upto 3rd Summary)</required>
         <vocabulary>ddcE</vocabulary>
    </field>
```

But now also it's not reflecting anything after restarting Tomcat.

Comment: I think I missed to add this in my answer, but anyways, just try. Add this line of code in your `dspace.cfg`: `authority.controlled.dc.subject.ddc= true`. Hopefully, your configuration will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to edit your `dspace.cfg`, look for the lines `vocabulary.plugin._plugin_.hierarchy.store` (`_plugin_` is the name of your enabled **DSpaceControlledVocabulary**, eg srsc). The default value is true, uncomment this and change the value to false.

**EDIT**

For example, if you used the default srsc controlled vocabulary:

```
## demo: subject code autocomplete, using srsc as authority
## (DSpaceControlledVocabulary plugin must be enabled)
## Warning: when enabling this feature any controlled vocabulary configuration in the input-forms.xml for the metadata field will be overridden.
choices.plugin.dc.subject = srsc
choices.presentation.dc.subject = lookup
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.store = false
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.suggest = false
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.delimiter = "::"
```

**UPDATE**

Add `authority.controlled.dc.subject = true` to the above configuration. So in your case, you should add `authority.controlled.dc.subject.ddc = true`.

---

Another option is to add `<property name="skipFirstNodeLevel" value="true"/>` in your discovery.xml

Ex.:

```
<bean id="searchFilterSubject" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.HierarchicalSidebarFacetConfiguration">
<property name="indexFieldName" value="subject"/>
<property name="metadataFields">
    <list>
        <value>dc.subject</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="sortOrder" value="COUNT"/>
<property name="splitter" value="::"/>
<property name="skipFirstNodeLevel" value="true"/>
```

I've never tried the latter option, so please try to modify your `dspace.cfg` first. Hope this help.

Comment: I have tried the second one, but it works partially.
I want to display only the last word from the total string of DDC subject, but using your solution it extracts like ->

in case of  "DEWEY DECIMAL CLASSIFICATION::GENERALITIES::Bibliography", it extracts -> "GENERALITIES", but I want to extract only the last portion i.e. "Bibliography".  
If the string is  "DEWEY DECIMAL CLASSIFICATION::Bibliography", then only it extracts -> "Bibliography".

Comment: May be more than one  "::" will be there in the whole string of 'DDC Subject', but I want to extract only the word after the last "::" . Is there any option like  "<property name="skipFirstNodeLevel" value="true"/>", to do it?
Please help.

Comment: I have tried the first one ,
in dspace.cfg, there was  **# vocabulary.plugin._plugin_.hierarchy.store = <true|false>**  .
      I have change it to  ->  **vocabulary.plugin._plugin_.hierarchy.store = <false>** .
But it is not reflecting anything.

Comment: You should replace **_plugin_** with your enabled **DSpaceControlledVocabulary** plugin. The example there in `dspace.cfg` is srsc, I assume you have enabled your custom **controlled vocabulary**, so change the string `_plugin_` with the name of your vocabulary. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu, I have edited my answer, I hope it is clearer now. And also, don't forget to uncomment. Sometimes a little typo can make us frustrated why what we expect to work is not working;) See also my comment above.

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu, did you try to reindex your dspace? Also, I assumed you enabled/uncommentd these lines from `dspace.cfg`: `plugin.selfnamed.org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthority = \
 org.dspace.content.authority.DCInputAuthority, \
 org.dspace.content.authority.DSpaceControlledVocabulary`. If you tried to upload a new item and when you get to the step where it asks you to lookup for subjects, are you still seeing all the nodes of your controlled vocabulary?

Comment: I have done everything now as per your suggestion. 
And when I am trying to upload any new items and when I get to the step where it asks to lookup for subjects, I am still seeing all the hierarchical nodes of controlled vocabulary.

Comment: Whatever be the hierarchy level of the items, I want to display the last part only.